# Finding the actual type (float, uint32_t...) based on the value of an enum (kFloat, kUint32...)

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, c++20

I am reading data from a file and the type of the data is stored as a `uint8_t` which indicates the type of data I am about to read. This is the enum corresponding to the declaration of these values.

```
enum DataType
{
    kInt8,
    kUint16,
    kInt16,
    kUint32,
    kInt32,
    kUint64,
    kInt64,
    kFloat16,
    kFloat32,
    kFloat64
};
```

I then get a function that reads the values stored in the file with the specific type, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
readData(T*& data, size_t numElements)
{
   ifs.read((char*)data, sizeof(T) * numElements);
}

uint8_t type;
ifs.read((char*)&type, 1);
uint32_t numElements;
ids.read((char*)&numElements, sizeof(uint32_t));
switch (type) {
    case kUint8:
        uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[numElements];
        readData<uint8_t>(data, numElements);
        // eventually delete mem
        ...
        break;
    case kUint16:
       uint16_t* data = new int16_t[numElements];
       readData<uint16_t>(data, numElements);
        // eventually delete mem
        ...
        break;
    case ... etc.
    default:
        break;
}
```

I have just represented 2 cases but eventually, you'd need to do it for all types. It's a lot of code duplication and so what I'd like to do is find the actual type of the values given the enum value. For example, if the enum value was `kUint32` then the type would be `uint32_t`, etc. If I was able to do so, the code could become more compact with something like this (pseudo-code):

```
DataType typeFromFile = kUint32;
ActualC++Type T = typeFromFile.getType();
readData<T>(data, numElements);
```

What technique could you recommend to make it work (or what alternative solution may you recommend?).

Comment: you need at least one level of indirection: `apply_type(typeFromFile, [&](auto type) { using T = typename decltype(type)::type; });`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @lorro it feels like the right idea) but I am yet to figure out your code in practice (sorry I am slow)). Could you elaborate a bit please to just let me see how this would be used in practice? and I will untangle the logic from there?) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to take a runtime value and map it to a compile-time type. Since C++ is a compile-time typed language, there's no escaping that, at some point, you're going to have to do something like a switch/case statement at some point. This is because each option needs to have its own separate code.

So the desire is to minimize how much of this you actually do. The best way to do it with standard library tools is to employ a `variant`.

So, you create a `variant<Ts>`, such that the  `Ts` types are `unique_ptr<T[]>`s, where the various `T`s are the sequence of types in your enumeration *in order*. This way, the enumeration index matches the `variant` index. The `unique_ptr` part is important, as it will make the `variant` destroy the array for you without having to know which type it stores.

So the only thing the `switch/case` needs to do is create the array. The processing of the array can happen in a visitor, which can be a template, [as follows](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rPssdv3sc):

```
    variant_type data_array{};

    switch (type) {
        case kUint8:
            data_array = std::make_unique<std::uint8_t[]>(numElements);
        case kUint16:
            data_array = std::make_unique<std::uint16_t[]>(numElements);
        default:
        //error out. `break` is not an option.
          break;
    }

    std::visit([&](auto &arr)
    {
        using arrtype = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(arr)>;
        readData<typename arrtype::element_type>(arr.get(), numElements);
       ///...
    }, data_array);

//data_array's destructor will destroy the allocated arrays.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a really cool answer. I have been using `std::unique_ptr` of course for the data allocation using get. so thanks for adding this in, it's reassuring to see. And the last bit (but not the least) you added is the glue I was lacking. Yes, you are also right to start pointing out that there will be code duplication at compile time. I had oversight of this to begin with. Super answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [higher-order macro](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/) for this sort of thing. Start with a macro that defines the mapping between the enum values and the types:

```
#define FOREACH_DATATYPE(OP)                    \
  OP(kUint8, uint8_t)                           \
  OP(kInt8, int8_t)                             \
  OP(kUint16, uint16_t)                         \
  OP(kInt16, int16_t)

  // Fill in the rest yourself
```

Then use it to generate the `switch` statement for all the enum values and types:

```
  switch (type) {
#define CASE_TYPE(name, type)                   \
    case name: {                                \
      type* data = new type[numElements];       \
      readData<type>(data, numElements);        \
      break;}
    FOREACH_DATATYPE(CASE_TYPE)
#undef CASE_TYPE
  default:
      break;
  }
```

Comment: This is a good answer) and I have seen such solutions indeed but while it makes the code more compact, you still have code duplication at compile time. While again this is a possible solution, I was hoping for something that would avoid that duplication at all.

Comment: @user18490 Do you do anything specific to the *type* (e.g. `int16_t`) inside every case branch? *If yes*, specific code for that type will have to be generated and the code will get duplicated anyway. *If no*, then a non-duplication approach may exist. For instance, `readData` could be made a *non-template* function that gets the size of every element as an `int` argument instead of using `sizeof(T)` and then you could just have an `std::map<DataType, int>` that defines how many bytes every enumed type uses.

Comment: Yes you are totally right about code duplication as mentioned in my comment to Nicol Bolas above (I had indeed oversight on this point). Thanks for pointing your second solution which is indeed possible and interesting,

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answer, another approach is to define a compile-time list of types first. Then you might assign enum values based on types (which prevents list vs. enum order issues) and have a `visit_nth` which calls the lambda with `id<type>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct id {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct list
{
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
    
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr size_t index_of = -1;
};

template<typename H, typename... Ts>
struct list<H, Ts...>
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Ts) + 1;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr size_t index_of =
        std::is_same_v<H, T> ? 0 : list<Ts...>::template index_of<T> + 1;

    template<typename F>
    static void visit_nth(size_t n, F f)
    {
        if constexpr (size > 0) {
            if (n > 0) {
                if constexpr (size > 1) {
                    list<Ts...>::visit_nth(n - 1, std::move(f));
                }
            } else {
                f(id<H>());
            }
        }
    }
};

using DataTypes = list<int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t>;

enum DataType
{
    kInt8   = DataTypes::index_of<int8_t>,
    kUint8  = DataTypes::index_of<uint8_t>,
    kInt16  = DataTypes::index_of<int16_t>,
    kUint16 = DataTypes::index_of<uint16_t>
};



int main()
{
    DataType typeFromFile = kUint8;
    DataTypes::visit_nth(typeFromFile, [&](auto type) {
        using T = typename decltype(type)::type;
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<T, uint8_t> << std::endl;
    });
}
```